# How to release a Mat that's being returned from a function?

Tags: java, android, opencv, mat

If inside a function I'm creating a new Mat and then I return that Mat, when does that Mat object ever get released?

Say I have this sample function:

```
    Mat sampleFunction(Mat frameHSV) {
    Mat filtered2 = new Mat();  // create a new Mat object 
    Mat frameRGB = new Mat();    // create a new Mat object
    Imgproc.cvtColor(frameHSV, frameRGB, Imgproc.COLOR_HSV2RGB); // convert to RGB

    Core.subtract(frameRGB, frameHSV, filtered2); // subtract Mats, just a made up operation here
    frameRGB.release(); // release the RGB mat to clear up memory
    return filtered2;
    }
```

So I'm passing in frameHSV, then I create two Mats inside the sample Function- filtered2 and frameRGB. FrameRGB is released by the end of the function, but Filtered2 is returned and so never released.

How do I release filtered2? Or is the release automatic when I return the Mat?

Comment: huh? obviously somthing like: `Mat frameHSV = new Mat(); Mat result = sampleFunction(frameHSV); use(result); frameHSV.release(); result.release();` ... `result.release()` will release `filtered2` as `result == filtered2`

Comment: D'oh- I feel silly. For some reason it didn't click to me that the Mat was just going to be passed back from the function. Thanks for clearing it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly question, but thank you Selvin for the quick answer.

As Selvin said, just release the result that's being called

```
  result = sampleFunction(frameHSV)
  result.release()  // releases the Mat that was returned from the function
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong but `Mat` should get released automatically after function call finished. Since the lifetime of the variable `filtered2` ends after function call.